# Makefile: why does it seem to add quotation marks around shell variables?

Tags: makefile

I have the following bash shell env set as follows:

```
AWS_REGION="us-east-1"
```

When I run the following in a bash shell things work no problem:

```
aws lambda update-function-code \
        --function-name ${LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME} \
        --zip-file fileb://mylambda.zip
```

However, when I try to run this exact same command in a Makefile like so:

```
deploy: .env mylambda.zip
    aws lambda update-function-code \
        --function-name ${LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME} \
        --zip-file fileb://mylambda.zip
```

... I get the following error:

```
Provided region_name '"us-east-1"' doesn't match a supported format.
make: *** [deploy] Error 255
```

My guess is that the Makefile runs in an environment that reads the env vars with extra quotation marks. Any ideas what's going on here and how to solve within the Makefile?

Comment: You need to reveal exactly how the Makefile is providing the value of `AWS_REGION`
to the shell that runs the `deploy` recipe. I speculate that it is via `.env`
but the evidence is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a line in my Makefile `include .env`, and therein the variable was defined as `export AWS_REGION="us-east-1"`. Apparently Make does not like such variables defined with quotation marks. Altering it to `export AWS_REGION=us-east-1` solved the problem.

Comment: That's because `include` assumes you're including a Makefile, and in Make, quotes are literal. You could do `. .env` instead as part of a recipe, which would make the *shell* source the file, and deal with quotes like the shell would.

Comment: Right.  It's not that make "does not like" variables defined with quotation marks.  It's that make does not interpret quotes in any special way.  To make, they're just characters like `a` or `b` or `5` or whatever.  So if you include quotes, the value will have quotes.  If you want to use `include .env` in your makefile you must ensure that the contents of `.env` contains only a strict overlapping subset of capabilities of shell variables and make variables.  This can be done, for strictly limited types of values.  Else source the file in the recipe as Benjamin suggests.